# Matching template template parameters with default arguments

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390236/template-template-parameters-and-default-arguments) and has to be with the specific cases below

```
template<class T, class U = T> class B { };
template <class ... Types> class C {  };
template<template<class> class P> class X { };

X<B>{ }; // OK
X<C>{ }; // OK
```

The standard in `[temp.arg.template]/3` has marked these two cases as OK but the last update on the [defect CWG 150](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150) says that the `CWG` has decided not take action yet. Neither `clang` nor `gcc` accept the code.

Are `clang` and `gcc` non-conformant?

Comment: The statement "The standard is wrong" does not compute. The standard is what it is; and clang or gcc either comply with the standard, or they do not. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc accepts this since 7.1. clang [intentionally](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#p0522) does not accept it unless you provide a new flag:

> Despite being the resolution to a Defect Report, this feature is disabled by default in all language versions, and can be enabled explicitly with the flag `-frelaxed-template-template-args` in Clang 4 onwards. The change to the standard lacks a corresponding change for template partial ordering, resulting in ambiguity errors for reasonable and previously-valid code. This issue is expected to be rectified soon.

For examples of said breaking code, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293162/2069064).

[Compilation demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Qw7k4c).

---

Also the latest update on the Core Issue in question is that it was:

> [Moved to DR at the November, 2016 meeting as paper [P0522R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0522r0.html).]

It's just at the top of the issue instead of the bottom. I added the link.